# Wordpress blog favicon problem

Tags: html, wordpress, header, favicon

I am trying to upload a favicon in my wordpress site. I have followed every step correctly but still its not showing the favicon. Fisrt I converted my pic to favicon.ico . Then I uploaded it to my root directory. Then I added the following code to my header.php file in the `<head>` tag :

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://misspassiton.com.au/favicon.ico" />
```

I have tried this one as well

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/favicon.ico" />
```

I have also visited : http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Favicon

but nothing seems to be working. I dont know whats wrong with it. I would be grateful, if anyone could help me

Regards

Omayr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your .ico file is corrupted. I can't open it in my browser. Other than that, it looks like you are doing everything ok.

If you can open http://misspassiton.com.au/favicon.ico directly in your browser, then you'll know it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Requesting http://misspassiton.com.au/favicon.ico, it responds but seems that the image is broken. So the href is ok ;)

2 suggestions:

- First: try to use a tool that
  converts images in ico (i.e.
  http://www.favicon.cc/)
- Second: if you want to use
  bloginfo(), you have to pass as
  parameter 'url' because if you pass 
  'template_directory' it will return
  'http://example/home/wp/wp-content/themes/parent-theme' that is completely wrong and as you can see it doesn't point to public root
  (see the [reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo))

**edit** : add also type on the link (for IE)

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://misspassiton.com.au/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
```

Comment: @Omayr what browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. The code below worked. Add to the header.php file right before the end head tag. Your image should be in the root of your wordpress installation.

```
/* ADD FAVICON */
<link rel="icon" href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```